# Scraping and downloading excel files using python from url

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, download

First question, so take it easy on me.

I'm trying to programmatically download all the excel files from a website using python. I'm very new to webscraping so my code my not be up to snuff - I've dropped in below. When I run the script, I'm not seeing any output and the files that I was meaning to download are nowhere to be found.

Not sure what I've got wrong or if I'm running the script wrong. I'm running it through anaconda navigator, navigating to the directory with the script and then running it using the below:

```
python file-scraper.py
```

Here is the code for my script. Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

DOMAIN = 'https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/'
URL = 'https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/Browse.aspx?startid=213973&row=1&dbid=0'
FILETYPE = '.xls'

def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    if FILETYPE in file_link:
        print(file_link)
        with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
            response = requests.get(DOMAIN + file_link)
            file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: you have the most common problem - browser use JavaScript to add links to page but request/beatifulsoup don't run JavaScript. You have to turn javaScript and check if you can get file without JavaScript. When I open your URL in browser without JavaScript then I don't see any `.xls`. I have to click some `year` and then it loads different URL with `.xls`. And you should use this different url instead your URL ie. https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/0/fol/213974/Row1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have the most common problem - browser uses `JavaScript` to add links to page (when you click year) but `requests`/`beatifulsoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

You have to turn off `JavaScript` in browser and check if you can get files in browser without `JavaScript`. And then you have to see how it works and do the same in code. But sometimes it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real browser which can run `JavaScript`.

---

When I open URL in browser without `JavaScript` then I don't see any `.xls`. I have to click `year` and then it loads different URL with `.xls`.

2017: https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/0/fol/213974/Row1.aspx
2018: https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/0/fol/285051/Row1.aspx
2019: https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/0/fol/312510/Row1.aspx
2020: https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/0/fol/384496/Row1.aspx
2021: https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/0/fol/466963/Row1.aspx

You have to use `beautifulsoup` to find these urls and load them with `requests` and then you should search `.xls`

---

**EDIT:**

Code searchs subpages and uses them to download files.

It downloads every year to separated folder.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os

# --- functions ---

def get_soup(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    #print(response.status_code)
    #print(response.text)
    html = response.text

    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    #soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    #soup = bs(html, 'html5lib')

    return soup

# --- main ---

# - data - 

DOMAIN = 'https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/'
URL = 'https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/Browse.aspx?startid=213973&row=1&dbid=0'
FILETYPE = '.xls'

# - code -

soup = get_soup(URL)
for folder_link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'DocumentBrowserNameLink'}):
    folder_name = folder_link.get('aria-label').split(' ')[0]
    folder_link = folder_link.get('href')

    print('folder:', folder_name)
    os.makedirs(folder_name, exist_ok=True)
    
    subsoup = get_soup(DOMAIN + folder_link)
    for file_link in subsoup.find_all('a', {'class': 'DocumentBrowserNameLink'}):
        file_name = file_link.get('aria-label')[:-4]  # skip extra `.xls` at the end
        file_link = file_link.get('href')
        
        if file_link.endswith(FILETYPE):
            print('  file:', file_name)
            file_name = os.path.join(folder_name, file_name)
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
                response = requests.get(DOMAIN + file_link)
                file.write(response.content)
```

---

**BTW:** I put it on GitHub [furas/python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/lfportal.loudoun.gov%20-%20requests%2C%20BS)

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage only contains the folders that, as a human you have to click in order to get the files.

With BS you have to get the links of the folders, then request them to get the file list.

What simplifies your case is that both folders and files have the class attribute DocumentBrowserNameLink.

You can have a function to find them

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

DOMAIN = 'https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/'
URL = 'https://lfportal.loudoun.gov/LFPortalinternet/Browse.aspx?startid=213973&row=1&dbid=0'
FILETYPE = '.xls'

def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

def get_links(page):
    result = page.find_all(class_="DocumentBrowserNameLink")
    return result

page = get_soup(URL)
folder_links = get_links(page)

for link in folder_links:
    page2 = get_soup(DOMAIN + link['href'])
    file_links = get_links(page2)

    for file in file_links:
        filepath = file['href']
        if FILETYPE in filepath:
            print(DOMAIN + filepath)
```